# Python Syntax to ListTables if does not contain *

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to create a list of tables on the condition that they do not contain 1 of 2 strings which would indicate the table is a view.  I have successfully built the table list with only 1 exclusion, but I can't figure out the syntax to include both exclusions.

The following line correctly builds a list excluding tables that contain the '.VW_' string.

```
tableList = [tb for tb in arcpy.ListTables('*.' + u + '.*') if '.VW_' not in tb]
```

And the following line correctly builds a list excluding tables that contain the '.TEMP_' string.

```
tableList = [tb for tb in arcpy.ListTables('*.' + u + '.*') if '.TEMP_' not in tb]
```

I have tried to combine the logic to exclude a table if it contains '.VW_' or '.TEMP_', but I can not seem to the syntax right.  The result of the following line includes all tables even if they have '.VW_' or '.TEMP_' in the name.

```
tableList = [tb for tb in arcpy.ListTables('*.' + u + '.*') if '.VW_' not in tb or '.TEMP_' not in tb]
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change the 'OR' to 'AND'.  You want to make sure that neither exist.  With OR, as long as one or the other doesn't exist it still passes the condition.

Comment: That fixed it! I thought the 'AND' would tell it to look for the existence of both the strings in one table name at the same time. Not the case though.